# Expose nested HTML property on asp.net UserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have an asp.net UserControl that writes HTML content from a SharePoint list to a Literal control. Currently I insert a title in h5 tags before each SharePoint list item I write to the Literal. Instead of having the title hardcoded to be placed in h5 tags, I'd like to expose a public property of my user control that lets me define the html format for the title. This is a little different from the templated user control questions I've found so many of because it's not really a template for the user control. I just need a string containing html. Here's what I'm looking to do:

```
public class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
    public string TitleFormat { get; set; }

    private void ShowContent()
    {
        ...
        string output = String.Format(TitleFormat, title) + someContent;
        ltlOutput.Text = output.
    }
}
```

In markup:

```
<UC:MyUserControl id="muc1" runat="server">
    <TitleFormat>
        <a href="www.somewhere.com"><h3>{0}</h3></a>
    </TitleFormat>
</UC:MyUserControl>
```

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer (provided by Decker Dong in the asp.net forums):

> To nest another class into one, you have to declare a new property but
>   just declare it is an InnerProperty. And set its Design properties.
>   Now here's a full sample for you:
>
> ```
> [ParseChildren(true),PersistChildren(false)]
> public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
> {
>     [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
>     [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
>     public string TitleFormat
>     {
>         get;
>         set;
>     }
>
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>     }
> }
> ```

With these attributes you can use the control as written in the question.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx

HTML

```
<test:NamingControl runat="server" ID="NamingControl" TitleFormat="This is myTitle">
    <TitleFormatTemplate>
         My title is <%# Container.TitleFormat %>
   </TitleFormatTemplate>
</test:NamingControl>
```

UserControl

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private ITemplate template;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string TitleFormat
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), 
    TemplateContainer(typeof(TitleFormatTemplate))]
    public ITemplate TitleFormatTemplate
    {
        get { return template; }
        set { template = value; }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        TitleFormatTemplate t = new TitleFormatTemplate();
        t.TitleFormat = this.TitleFormat;
        template.InstantiateIn(t);
        this.Controls.Add(t);
        this.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Child Control - INamingContainer

```
public class TitleFormatTemplate : Control, INamingContainer
{
    private string _TitleFormat = "";
    public string TitleFormat
    {
        get { return _TitleFormat; }
        set { _TitleFormat = value; }
    }
}
```

**The simpler approach** - No more TitleFormat tag

MyUserControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyUserControl.ascx.cs"      
    Inherits="testgingweb.usrcontrols.MyUserControl" %>

<a href="www.somewhere.com"><h3><asp:Label runat="server" ID="PassedValueLabel"></asp:Label</h3></a>
```

The Codebehind - MyUserControl.ascx.cs

```
public string TitleFormat
{
    get { return ViewState["TitleFormat"]; }
    set { ViewState["TitleFormat"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PassedValueLabel.Text = String.Format("Whatever {0} here", this.TitleFormat);
}
```

HTML

```
<test:MyUserContorl runat="server" ID="NamingControl" TitleFormat="This is myTitle">
</test:MyUserContorl>
```

Notice that I didn't have the `TitleFormat` tag anymore.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. I don't think this will work for what I'm doing. You've sort of redefined my goal. I'm going to be inserting a dynamic number of titles so I can't have a property for each one. I don't really need an ITemplate or anything instantiated in the control either. It would be overkill. I just want to declare a string property as a child of the user control in markup. The value of the string property just happens to be HTML. Are you saying that can't be done?

Comment: The markup `<TitleFormat>` you used as child element to your control can only work with ITemplate. Without that you can't do it declaratively. Check my updated answer to see the other approach

Comment: "The markup <TitleFormat> you used as child element to your control can only work with ITemplate" - False. See marked answer.